# What is the name of this flower?

Tags: botany, species-identification, flowers

A flower has grown on a **leaf** in our garden. What is the name of this flower? Give some description.[image]

Comment: This searchable image database may have the flower you are looking for.
http://plants.usda.gov/gallery.html

Comment: Please indicate where this is located.

Comment: Great picture of what looks like a cactus; cf "White Torch Cactus". However, it would be helpful to have a picture of the leaf, and to know where and when this was flowering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to me to be a Night Blooming Cereus:

[image]

We had one in our greenhouse in Botany. It rarely bloomed, and the bloom was wilted by mid-morning.

> Night-blooming cereus is the common name referring to **a large number of flowering ceroid cacti that bloom at night**. The flowers are short lived, and some of these species, such as Selenicereus grandiflorus, bloom only once a year, for a single night. <sub><sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night-blooming_cereus)</sup></sub>

[Dave's garden](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/2443/) lists it as "Dutchman's Pipe Cactus, Night blooming Cereus"
*Epiphyllum oxypetalum*.