# Can anybody identify this plant?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I'm from Brazil. And I have this plant at home.

Can anybody identify this plant?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Strongly related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36542/what-is-the-name-of-this-flower

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [Epiphyllum Oxypetalum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphyllum_oxypetalum). Epi is greek for around (epi-center) and phyto is plant, epiphytes are plants that live on other plants, for example rainforest plants that grow on the canopy of tall trees.

There are lots of hybrids and [lots of colors](https://www.google.fr/search?q=cactus%20orchid&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixs9mu1OTYAhUE2qQKHdfyC7YQ_AUICigB&biw=1034&bih=579&dpr=2.25).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a water loving cactus from Central America, I have some but I do not know the latin name. I asked a similar question.